# How to get domain name of laptop

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, hostname, domain-name, client-certificate

I need to create a `certificate signing request` to get a certificate from a `CA` for my laptop:

```
 openssl req -subj "/CN=<my common name>" -new -key client-key.pem -out client.csr
```

In order to define `/CN` I should get a `hostname` and `domainname` of my laptop because:

```
/CN =  hostname + domainname
```

But when I run in the console:

```
~/D/M/certs ❯❯❯ domainname 
(none)
```

How to correcltly define `/CN`?

Comment: CN (Common Name) can be anything, really. What do you want to use the certificate for?

Comment: @DanielB for docker swarm tls authentication.

Comment: I see. It doesn’t look like Docker will do anything but check it’s from a trusted CA. Just use a name you’re comfortable with. If you’re setting stuff up, you MUST NOT use an external CA or you will allow access to anyone that can acquire certificates signed by it.